# how can a UILongPressGestureRecognizer change the present view to another View Controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

How do I programmatically change from my 1st view controller to my 2nd view controller, which in storyboard is linked to the 1st in storyboard?

My iPad storyboard has a Tab Bar Controller as the "initial View Controller", 
which links through a "Relationship Seque view controllers" 
to a Navigation Controller, which links through a "root view" link, to View Controller A, which has a UIButton, which links through a 'Manual Seque push' to View Controller B.

Tab Bar Cntrl => Navigation Cntrlr ==(root view)==> View Cntrl A, UIButton ==(push)==> View Cntrl B

So, when running, with View Controller A shown, pressing its UIButton causes the view to change to View Controller B.

There's another UIButton on a UITableView cell on View Controller A.  When I press and hold this button, the delegate for UILongPressGestureRecognizer fires ok, and I need View Controller B to now be the view.

How then do I change from View Controller A to View Controller B?
And with VC B open, how do I change back to VC A ?

THE DELEGATE THAT RESPONDS TO PRESS-AND-HOLD............
- (void)schedule_long_press_delegate:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        printf("Long press Ended .................  \n");

```
    // Get storyboard:
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad"
                                                             bundle: nil];
    printf("mainStoryboard = %x \n", (int)mainStoryboard ); // !!! ax

    // Get nav controller for MANAGE view:
    UINavigationController *MANAGE_UINavigationController = (UINavigationController*)[mainStoryboard 
                        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"MANAGE_Storyboard_ID"];
    printf("MANAGE_UINavigationController = %x  \n", (int)MANAGE_UINavigationController ); // !!! ax


    // Get MANAGE view's view controller:
    SCHEDULE_UIViewController *schedule_UIViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:
                                        NSStringFromClass([SCHEDULE_UIViewController class])];
    printf("schedule_UIViewController = %x  \n", (int)schedule_UIViewController ); // !!! ax

    // Change screen to MANAGE view:
    [MANAGE_UINavigationController  pushViewController: schedule_UIViewController animated:YES];
}
else {
    printf("Long press detected .....................   \n");
}
```

}

STORYBOARD SETTINGS:
UITabBarController  ... Storyboard ID is blank.
..links to:
UINavigationController ...  Class=UINavigationController  StoryboardID = "MANAGE_Storyboard_ID"
..links to:
UIViewController ... Class=acc   StoryboardID is blank     (INITIAL VIEW)
..links to:
UIViewController ... Class & StoryboardID = "SCHEDULE_UIViewController"    (TARGET VIEW)

OUTPUT:..........

mainStoryboard = 1f8b4900
MANAGE_UINavigationController = 1e5d45f0
schedule_UIViewController 2     = 1e5d4b20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the delegate method for the long press gesture recognizer you can push view controller B from code like this:

```
ViewControllerB *viewControllerB = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([ViewControllerB class])];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES];
```

You can use a different identifier if you want; using the class name is just my preference.

Changing back to view controller A will be handled for you by the navigation controller. The user will be presented with a back button in the upper left corner.

Comment: Still doesn't work.  So, I now get storyboard, get nav controller, get target view controller, all points are set, do the push: no effect!

Comment: My storyboard's initial view is the tab bar.  Does that matter? tab bar --> nav cntrl --> view cntrl A --> view cntrl B.  I am at A when button long pressed, and want to go to B, but nothing happens.

Comment: Did you said the view controller's storyboard identifier in storyboard? Make sure by selecting the view controller in the storyboard editor (not one of its subviews), clicking the identity inspector, and making sure both the "Class" and "Storyboard ID" fields are set exactly to "SCHEDULE_UIViewController" (without the quotes).

Comment: Yes, they are: view cntrl B (target) Storyboard ID = Class = class name = "SCHEDULE_UIViewController".  View Cntrl A Storyboard ID is not set, since I don't reference it.  I updated Question with all these Storybook details, and the code.

Comment: Does view cntrl B need to be instantiated or initialized ahead of time, before the push?

Comment: In the target view cntrl selection, does it matter if I use self.storyboard or mainStoryboard

Comment: As long as both views are designed in the same storyboard file you can just use self.storyboard. The call to the storyboard to `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` will take care of instantiating the new VC and initializing it with the storyboard design, you don't need to do anything else. What class is that delegate method in? That is, what is `self`? I'm assuming it's view controller A; is that correct? I use this method all day, so there's some other issue going on in your setup.